# Apache/Nginx with Docker works fine in Windows but not in Linux

Tags: docker, apache, nginx, docker-compose, http-status-code-403

I have this this environment mounted with docker in Windows (11) and works fine but when I try to mount in Linux (mint) I always got a 403 error, both with Apache and Nginx but only in this specific Linux. Tried to reinstall everything, set permissions, check ports, nothing works. Can someone help me? I'm running out of ideas. This is the error:

```
[core:crit] [pid 18] (13)Permission denied: [client 172.18.0.1:48670] AH00529: /var/www/html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/var/www/html/' is executable
```

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4.1-apache

USER root

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt update && apt install -y \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        zip \
        curl \
        unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-source delete

COPY apache/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html && a2enmod rewrite
```

This is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
    app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: laravel
        container_name: app
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
        networks:
            - laranet

    mysql:
        image: mysql
        container_name: db
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        volumes:
            - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - laranet

networks:
    laranet:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    mysqldata:
        driver: local
```

And this is the vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Comment: Did you create a docker group and add yourself to it? https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Comment: @Jacques yes, I followed every step in the documentation.